# Gamestate not functioning properly

Tags: c#, xna

All three of my screen/states works fine, however, i implemented a fourth one to act as an information screen. Fine so far, but when i run the game, and press the 'H' key, it doesn't change the screen to another background (what I have done so far). Below is the code:

```
public void UpdateInformation(GameTime currentTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.H))
    {
        GameState = 4;
    } // GAMESTATE 4 which is the instruction/Information screen.
}
```

This is the code for the game state in the update method:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    switch (GameState)
    {
        case 1: UpdateStarted(gameTime);
            break;

        case 2: UpdatePlaying(gameTime);
            break;

        case 3: UpdateEnded(gameTime);
            break;

        case 4: UpdateInformation(gameTime);
            break;
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Here i am drawing the screen.

```
public void DrawInformation(GameTime currentTime) 
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(InfoBackground, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Below is the draw information code for the states:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    switch (GameState)
    {
        case 1: DrawStarted(gameTime);
            break;

        case 2: DrawPlaying(gameTime);
            break;

        case 3: DrawEnded(gameTime);
            break;

        case 4: DrawInformation(gameTime);
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, it's just my H key is not responding, but my S key responds well and starts the game. Are four state/screens compatible with 'Gamestate'?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `H` key will not work, because your Update code for the `H` key is in UpdateInformation...

What it actually does is: If you're in the Information screen, press H to go to the Information screen (which doesn't make sense)

You should move your `H` detection code somewhere more appropriate. Where is your `S` detection code?

Also, I would recommend using an enum instead of numbers for your game states.

```
enum gameStates
{
    Started,
    Playing,
    Ended,
    Information,
}
```

That way, it's much easier to maintain and understand. (See example below)

```
switch(GameState)
{
    case gameStates.Started:
         //Do something
         break;
}
```